# gles2 Moving a sprite with an AnalogController

Tags: android, andengine

Hello I am new to andengine and I have been using the andengine cookbook and have reached the part about creating an analogcontroller.  I have written some code to move and rotate a sprite but whenever I run it I get a runtime error.

```
mController = new AnalogOnScreenControl(controllerX, controllerY,
mCamera, controllerBaseregion, controllerknobregion, 0.1f,
mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager(),
new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener() {
    @Override
    public void onControlChange(
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // pvalues is the direction of dragging
    BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,
    float pValueX, float pValueY) {
        mainSprite.setPosition(mainSprite.getX() + (pValueX + 2),
        mainSprite.getY() + (pValueY + 2 ));
        mainSprite.setRotation(pValueX);
        Log.d("mainSprite", String.valueOf(mainSprite.getRotation()));
    }
```

Comment: you should share the logcat output related to the error

Comment: I can't run it on my emulator. I have to export it to my phone because the computer I use has a bad graphics card.

Comment: when I comment out the setPosition and set Rotation code the analog controller works fine.

Comment: if you leave your phone hooked up it should record the error in logcat. I'll look again at your code in the morning to see if the other comments make any sense to me.

Comment: it's possible that you need to be doing those on the updateThread - see my other answers for more on that concept

Comment: Yeah I will check that out, what I was trying to say is when I comment out these three lines mainSprite.setPosition(mainSprite.getX() + (pValueX + 2), mainSprite.getY() + (pValueY + 2 )); mainSprite.setRotation(pValueX); my analog controller shows up fine, but it does not move my sprite because the onControlChange() method is empty. So the error involves something in my onControlChange() method

Comment: My log cat is as follows(I downloaded an app on my phone to see it)   at com.bradquarantine.Gameactivity$1.onControlChange(GameActivity.java:189)  line 189 is as follows mainSprite.setPosition(mainSprite.getX() + (pValueX + 2),